# Angularfire 2 Firebase storage nested subscribe

Tags: javascript, ionic2, observable, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Im preparing an update form.

I have a component and  a service which are getting post detail with $id from Firebase database as Angularfire2 FirebaseObjectObservable.

Then call a service to get image's metadata from firebase storage on pageload Ionic 2.

But observable on service getting result after page loaded. So form inputs always empty.

Is it possible to wait for callback getting firebase storage metadata then continue??

This is component

```js
ionViewDidLoad()  {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'hide',
      content: 'Loading Please Wait...'
    });
   
    loading.present();
    this.categories = this.af.database.list('/Categories');
    let id = this.navParams.get('id'); 
    
    this.post = this.af.database.object(`/Posts/${id}`);
    
    this.post.subscribe(snapshot => {
      
      this.uploadImagesService.getMetaData(snapshot.postpicurl).subscribe((metadata:any) =>{
        //Set Form values   
        this.CreatePost.get('title').setValue(snapshot.title);
        this.CreatePost.get('content').setValue(snapshot.content);
        this.uploadedpic.name = metadata.name;
        this.uploadedpic.size = metadata.size;

      });
      console.log(snapshot);
      
    });
    
      
    loading.dismiss();
      
  }
```

This is metadata service

```js
getMetaData(url:string){
   return Observable.create((observer:any) => {
     let metaDataRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL(url);
     metaDataRef.getMetadata().then(function(metadata) {
      // Metadata now contains the metadata for 'images/forest.jpg'
       observer.next(metadata);
      //observer.complete(metadata);
     }).catch(function(error){
       observer.error(error);
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved Like this. Because I learned that firebase always return promise.

```js
getMetaData(url:string){
 
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     let metaDataRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL(url);
     const getmetadata = metaDataRef.getMetadata().then(resolve, reject);
     getmetadata.then((metadata:any) =>{
       resolve(metadata);
     },(error:any) =>{
       reject(error);
     });
 
   });
 }
```